# Required dependency on parent directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a `<layout>` directive that will consist of a number of `<pane>` elements.

Is it possible to create the pane directive such that it's instructions only apply when found within a `<layout>` element?

The documentation states:

> require - Require another controller be passed into current directive
>   linking function. The require takes a name of the directive controller
>   to pass in. If no such controller can be found an error is raised.

Using `require: '^layout'`, when a `<pane>` element is found outside a `<layout>` element an error does get thrown, however the dom element is still transformed. Can the directive be defined to restrict it's behaviour to the scope of a `<layout>` element?

What if I needed another pane directive with different instructions inside a `<grid>` element?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way (maybe not the best way) to do it:  define a controller on your `layout` directive, then optionally `require` it with `^?` in your `layout` directive.  In your link function, check to see if the layoutCtrl is defined:

```
require: '^?layout',
link: function(scope, element, attrs, layoutCtrl) {
   if(!layoutCtrl) return;  // do nothing if no layout
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/2pwLn/).